# Android System Gesture Exclusion area persists after leaving the screen

Tags: android, android-view

I use `setSystemGestureExclusionRects()` method to set a single exclusion Rect inside onDraw method of my custom View, which resides inside a Fragment. It works. However, after I navigate back from that Fragment, the exclusion area persists and affects all other screens in the app.

Furthermore, even if I try to clear the exclusion rects in this manner, the exclusion area persists:

```
    override fun onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow()
        systemGestureExclusionRects = listOf()
    }
```

Two questions:

1. Is there really a requirement to clear the exclusion Rect's?
2. How can I resolve the "persistent" exclusion area that remains after I navigate back from the Fragment?

Answer (score 0):

The article [Gesture Navigation: handling gesture conflicts (III)](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/gesture-navigation-handling-gesture-conflicts-8ee9c2665c69)
mentions

> SeekBar actually does this automatically for you in Android 10, so
> there’s no need to do this yourself. It’s just as an example to show
> you the general pattern.

I've checked the [AbsSeekBar](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/main/core/java/android/widget/AbsSeekBar.java#759) implementation. I don't see the method `setSystemGestureExclusionRects` being called from `onLayout` or `onDraw`. However, it is called from [setThumbPos](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/main/core/java/android/widget/AbsSeekBar.java#1155) which is called from `onVisualProgressChanged`. Unfortunately, I have no idea when the overloaded `setSystemGestureExclusionRects` gets called and how the underlying rects get cleared out. It seems though that the trick is to capture [mGestureExclusionRects](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/main/core/java/android/widget/AbsSeekBar.java#104) and extend those with the rect from your custom view implementation.

Sorry for not answering your question, but I hope that my findings might help us all to figure out the mystery.

Best regards, Tom.